# JavaScript IF statement not acting as expected

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My IF statement isn't acting as I would expect it to. It will only fire the email if the work flow state is set to "cleanup_batch". It does not fire if the the work flow state is "importing".

```
function sendEmail() {

    var rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues()
    var flatrows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues().flat();
    var pendingCounter = flatrows.filter(x => x == 'created').length;

    rows.forEach(function(rows, index) {
        if (index !== 0) {
            var rowId = rows[0]
            var rowUpdatedAt = new Date(rows[3])
            var mmTimeUpdatedAt = rowUpdatedAt.getTime()
            var rowProgress = rows[5]
            var rowWorkFlow = rows[6]
            var rightNow = new Date()
            var mmRightNow = rightNow.getTime()
            if (mmRightNow - mmTimeUpdatedAt >= notificationTime && (rowWorkFlow === "importing") || (rowWorkFlow === "cleanup_batch")) {
                MailApp.sendEmail(email,
                    "IMPORTANT: Canvas SIS Import Notification",
                    "Hello, SIS import " + rowId + " is taking longer than expected. It is in the " + rowWorkFlow + " work flow state and is at " + rowProgress + " progress. You also have " + pendingCounter + " pending imports.If you would like to abort it, go to your SIS Import Notification Google Sheet and go to Canvas in the tool bar, click on Abort SIS Import and type in " + rowId + ". If you would like to abort all pending SIS imports as well, go to your SIS Import Notification Google Sheet and go to Canvas in the tool bar, click on Abort All Pending SIS Imports."
                )
            } else if ((rowWorkFlow === "failed") || (rowWorkFlow === "failed_with_messages")) {
                MailApp.sendEmail(email,
                    "IMPORTANT: Canvas SIS Import Notification",
                    "Hello, SIS import " + rowId + " has " + rowWorkFlow + ". Just a friendly heads up!"
                )
            } else {
                return
            }
        }
    })
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should wrap the OR condition in a group: `&& ((rowWorkFlow === "importing") || (rowWorkFlow === "cleanup_batch"))` Or throw `'importing'` and `'cleanup_batch'` into a `Set()` object and call `set.has(rowWorkFlow)` to allow multiple checks.

Comment: You should always consider taking problems like this and isolating them in a simpler code so that you can gain a better understanding of how certain feature work.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your check by using "fail early" pattern, also it would be easier to evalute function body if you'd extract your conditions into variables

```
function sendEmail() {
  var rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  var flatrows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
    .getDataRange()
    .getValues()
    .flat();
  var pendingCounter = flatrows.filter((x) => x == "created").length;

  rows.forEach(function (rows, index) {
    if (index === 0) return;

    var rowId = rows[0];
    var rowUpdatedAt = new Date(rows[3]);
    var mmTimeUpdatedAt = rowUpdatedAt.getTime();
    var rowProgress = rows[5];
    var rowWorkFlow = rows[6];
    var rightNow = new Date();
    var mmRightNow = rightNow.getTime();

    var shouldSendEmail =
       rowWorkFlow === "cleanup_batch" ||
    (rowWorkFlow === "importing" && mmRightNow - mmTimeUpdatedAt >= notificationTime);

    if (!shouldSendEmail) return;

    var failedWorkflow =
      rowWorkFlow === "failed" || rowWorkFlow === "failed_with_messages";

    if (failedWorkflow) {
      return MailApp.sendEmail(
        email,
        "IMPORTANT: Canvas SIS Import Notification",
        "Hello, SIS import " +
          rowId +
          " has " +
          rowWorkFlow +
          ". Just a friendly heads up!"
      );
    }

    MailApp.sendEmail(
      email,
      "IMPORTANT: Canvas SIS Import Notification",
      "Hello, SIS import " +
        rowId +
        " is taking longer than expected. It is in the " +
        rowWorkFlow +
        " work flow state and is at " +
        rowProgress +
        " progress. You also have " +
        pendingCounter +
        " pending imports.If you would like to abort it, go to your SIS Import 
Notification Google Sheet and go to Canvas in the tool bar, click on Abort SIS 
Import and type in " +
        rowId +
        ". If you would like to abort all pending SIS imports as well, go to 
your SIS Import Notification Google Sheet and go to Canvas in the tool bar, 
click on Abort All Pending SIS Imports."
    );
  });
}
```

From here it gets a bit easier to try different expressions inside "flag" variables to find out the correct one.

*PS I didn't change logic, just simplified it a bit so you could try to crack the nut yourself, I'm sure you will succeed with a bit more readable version*